# Setting fonts in a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I've got a JTextArea which has the following text "Text1 Text2 Text3". 
Is there a way I can make  all of them different fonts? E.g. "Text1" is bold, "Text2" is italic and "Text3" is normal?

I know I can create a Font object, however I can only apply it the JTextArea object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [is not possible](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) in JTextArea. But you can use JTextPane or JEditorPane.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try using a JTextPane.